# How to create a custom Lexer for WxPython STC

Tags: python, python-3.x, scintilla, wxpython

I am creating a WxPython App which has an STC Widget displaying JSON. I checked all the available Lexers [here](https://wiki.wxpython.org/StyledTextCtrl%20Lexer%20Quick%20Reference) but I found that they don't have a JSON Lexer.

After surfing the net I found that we can create custom lexers for STC by setting `wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl().SetLexer()` to `stc.STC_LEX_CONTAINER`. But the problem is that I don't know which Tokens it gives out how to highlight the code.

Please tell how to do it or if there are any tutorials.

Comment: It's a little bit complicated, it involves many steps. I created a glsl code editor.First time instead of using lexers, i just used regular expressions to parse trough the text, and highlight the keywords, and it works fine.Then i created a second version using custom lexers, but its still not finished.

Comment: could you please tell the steps. Or else maybe the Tokens passed out by stc.STC_LEX_CONTAINER. I guess it would be easy to make one for JSON